# Why Ubuntu is slow after downloading netbeans

Tags: xubuntu, java, jdk, netbeans

Ubuntu slow down is net beans for Ubuntu is virus cuz my pc start acting weird after downloading net bean . Here update now my eclipse crashes after opening desgin tab .i think there problem in java sdk i m usng oracle jdk every time it crashes a crash report created

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb2c85942b7, pid=7654, tid=0x00007fb37dd40700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x4e2b7]  gdk_display_open+0x57
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fb37400b000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=7655, stack(0x00007fb37dc40000,0x00007fb37dd41000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000114

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007fb2cc7fa8d0, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00007fb37dd3c980, RBP=0x00007fb37dd3c990, RSI=0x00007fb2c85940b0, RDI=0x00007fb2cc7fa8d0
R8 =0x00007fb2cc7f9190, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000009, R11=0x0000000000017101
R12=0x00007fb2c9cf9bb0, R13=0x00007fb2c9cf2710, R14=0x00007fb3742af780, R15=0x00007fb2cc7e62e8
RIP=0x00007fb2c85942b7, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000006
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fb37dd3c980)
0x00007fb37dd3c980:   61626c6c6f726373 6e75203a6f732e72
0x00007fb37dd3c990:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fb37dd3c9a0:   2064656e69666564 203a6c6f626d7973
0x00007fb37dd3c9b0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fb37dd3c9c0:   75646f6d5f6b7467 6c707369645f656c
0x00007fb37dd3c9d0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007fb37dd3c9e0:   0000000000000000 00007fb2cc7e6340
0x00007fb37dd3c9f0:   00007fb2c9cf2710 00007fb3742af780
0x00007fb37dd3ca00:   00007fb2cc7e62e8 00007fb37d1c098c
0x00007fb37dd3ca10:   00007fb2cc7e6340 0000000000000000
0x00007fb37dd3ca20:   0000000000000001 e7a001fd974ae500
0x00007fb37dd3ca30:   0000000000000000 0000000000000001
0x00007fb37dd3ca40:   00007fb37dd3cae0 00007fb2c9cf9bb0
0x00007fb37dd3ca50:   00007fb2c9cf2710 00007fb3742af780
0x00007fb37dd3ca60:   00007fb2cc7e62e8 00007fb2c8563fcf
0x00007fb37dd3ca70:   0000000000000001 0000000000000001
0x00007fb37dd3ca80:   00007fb37dd3cae0 00007fb2c892b522
0x00007fb37dd3ca90:   00007fb37dd3cae0 00007fb2c9d03c91
0x00007fb37dd3caa0:   00007fb37400b1f8 000000000000000c
0x00007fb37dd3cab0:   00007fb2cc5abf88 00007fb2c9afba38
0x00007fb37dd3cac0:   0000000000000000 00007fb2c9afba38
0x00007fb37dd3cad0:   00007fb37dd3cb58 00007fb37400b000
0x00007fb37dd3cae0:   00007fb37dd3caf0 00007fb2c9cfe0c9
```

The list goes on.

Comment: I highly doubt NetBeans is the culprit. Have you run top or htop from a terminal? This should give you an idea of what processes are running on your box.

Comment: As above, but with even higher doubts.